# USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED Intent not firing - no HID device, no device filter

Tags: android, usb

I've some problem catching USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED intent.
In AndroidManifest i've not specified any device filter, only the feature

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html). 
Also my device is not a HID device, and i've correctly set up the USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED intent, but it never fires.

I don't want to use the getDeviceList() function to list attached devices, because I do not know the right time to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a device filter; it's stated right there in the document you linked to:

> If you want your application to be notified of an attached USB device, specify an `<intent-filter>` and `<meta-data>` element pair for the `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` intent in your main activity.